# try catch optimization with fixed array points inside a loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

Is there a better way of doing the following. I have a JSON array that gets passed in a javascript object, the object doesn't have key value pairs so i need to manual set each point in the array and bind it to a variable.

While the example bellow is only 1 item there are 80+ that need to be set.

If i try to put in `item[key][2][1]` as a peramiter for a function the code fails as it trys to access the array before passing off to the try catch function. Also all the try catch's happen within a loop that can run up to 200 times per page load.

The below works for everything, but when dealing with i.e 8 or below it begins to bottleneck fast. I have also isolated that it is this checking function that bottlenecks and not other parts of the code.

```
 var someArr = "";
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var item = data[i];
     for(key in item){    
        try{someArr = item[key][2][1]}
        catch(err){}
        final{someArr = checkData(someArr)}
      }
    }
    function checkData(value){
      if(!value){value = "";}
      return value;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What's the try-catch supposed to do in there at all?

Comment: Couldn't this be entirely replaced by `someArr = item[key][2][1] || ''` ? Or am I missing something? I'm possibly confused by your naming a string as something-"Arr"

Comment: So its a large dataset that gets downloaded and displayed. Sometime entire sections are not included from the JSON data. meaning that arrays don't get included, so i have set the specific pointer to look at, but at time it dones't exist so the code fails as it can't access that array point.

Comment: @moopet sorry somArr is a variable but it my live code i set it to an array as it needs to check cahsed data and new data, for the example i should of just called it someVar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exchange your try catch block with a check if the parts of variable are set.

```
if (item && item[key] && item[key][2]) {
    someArr = item[key][2][1];
}
```

Comment: doesnt' work as if the part of the array doesn't exist it fails and i get a console error of 
`VM120:201 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Comment: the condition checks for truty values. (maybe you missed the open curly bracket.)

Comment: no, it can't access the array because it doesn't exists at all, but it will at time. this is why the try catch currently works, but im looking for an alternative

Comment: but when the array does not exist, then the first `item` or the second `item[key]` returns a falsy value and the if part is skipped.

Comment: So it is, sorry i thought i refreshed my browser when i tried.